# insert symbols into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, urlencode

I have this web service

`http://www.example.com/addregisteredusers.php?emailId=test@tets.com&userName=`

php code:

```
    $emailId=$_REQUEST['emailId'];      
$userName=$_REQUEST['userName'];

    $insertDetails=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `registration` (`userName`, `emailId`) VALUES ('$userName', '$emailId')");
```

when go to database the userName field is empty.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: What collation do you use?

Comment: You have no error checking in place to see if the query was successful or to report any messages if it was not.

Comment: collation: utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Quentin: so if i use mysqli this issue will be solved?

Comment: What are those symbol you inserted in Username text?

Comment: How did you realise that your username field was empty? The characters you are trying to insert are very rare indeed, and I would expect them to be unsupported by most fonts, including, for instance, the font used by your console. Perhaps your data was in fact correctly inserted.

Comment: someone tried to register with these chars, what can i do with him?

Comment: type:   in this comment how stackoverflow dealing with them and store them into database and print them  correctly !!!!

Comment: @AymanHussein I see only boxes. Are these special characters are like Copyright symbol, smileys?

Comment: not boxes, your browser seems can not handle them or your os is not have the correct font.  what is your browser and os you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I have created table with fields like below screens

Structure of table

[image]

Datas in the table

[image]

I have used this code.

```
     $emailId = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['uname']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `new` (`userName`, `emailId`) VALUES ('$userName', '$emailId')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: field type: varchar(500)

Comment: if you use this code, did you get any error from mysql_error() ?

Comment: no errors and the record added successfully to db with empty userName

Comment: the issue is not in escape string the issue in symbols

Comment: yeah. i created same fields in my table. when i run query it is working fine for me. i used utf8_general_ci as collation

Comment: I have tried your solution before and did not work, the issue is not in single or double quotation the issue in symbols

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem by change table and field charset from utf8 to utf8mb4

Answer (score -1):

please run this one

```
$insertDetails = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `registration` (`userName`, `emailId`) VALUES ('".$userName."', '".$emailId."')");
```

Comment: Why would using string concatenation instead of interpolation help?

Comment: Because variables are only recognized in single quotes, not double quotes.